# Is it bad practice to calculate a method once and save the result?

Tags: java, methods, return

I initially took the gung ho approach in Java of deriving everything, minimizing the use of properties and calculating methods on the fly, every time. But for larger datasets I started running into performance issues, and calling the same method multiple times to only calculate the same result seemed redundant and sometimes an exponential drag to performance.

I finally started taking the approach for data-intensive operations of setting my methods to calculate only the first time it is called and save the result for any future returns.

Is this bad practice?

Comment: From the context of the question, I would argue for "no, it's not bad practice", I would however suggest that you make sure you know when the value will need to re-calculated to ensure that the result is always correct for your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not bad. It is actually a **good practice**.

First, if you're calculating data and doing it AGAIN then you do are committing a huge crime in Java. As you've said, we have to **minimize the use of memory** and calculation takes a lot of memory.

Second, it is one of the best practices to **calculate the operations for the first time and save it in a variable**. For the next time you need that value again, simply call the variable.

Comment: Beware of premature optimization!!

Answer (score 7):

> Is it bad practice to calculate a method once and save the result?

There is no correct general answer to this<sup>1</sup>.  It depends on the circumstances.

- It (IMO) is **bad practice** to do this everywhere *as a matter of habit*.  The JIT compiler is capable of various automatic optimizations that make this hand optimization pointless ... or even harmful.  (Generally speaking, hand optimizations are not worthwhile unless you have profiled the complete application using realistic input data, and the profiling tells you that you have a performance hotspot at a particular point in the code.)

  If you do this as a matter of habit (i.e. without thinking), you are probably making your code less readable, and possibly making it slower rather than faster.  And if you are thinking about it each time you code a method call, that is going to impact on your productivity.
- It is **not bad practice** to do this when you have solid reasons to believe that the method call is likely to be expensive.  However, consider that your intuition may be wrong, and that it may be better to rely on profiling to tell you where to spend your efforts.  (See note above on productivity.)
- It is **good practice** to do this if you have determined that performance is a real concern based on application-level benchmarking, AND you have determined by profiling that hand optimization of these calls is warranted.
- It is **necessary** if the method has side-effects and you don't want the side-effects to happen twice.
- It is **incorrect** if the method has side-effects and you need the side-effects to happen each time.

---

The other thing to consider through all of is whether this helps or hinders readability ... and whether maintainability is more or less important to your project than performance.

---

<sup>1 ... and the answers that claim there is are over-generalizing and/or being overly dogmatic.  Seriously guys, it is NOT that simple.</sup>

Comment: Well for this specific, case I was going through an 250-item ArrayList against 350,000 objects to retrieve what could only be one of a few possible combinations. I mapped those possible combinations and prevented them from being recalculated every single time the method was called. By my calculations, performance went from 3 days to 16 minutes.

Comment: @ThomasNield - The fact that this worked for you in a specific case DOES NOT allow you to conclude that it is *always* "good practice" or "bad practice".  That seems to be what your Question is asking.

Comment: @racerrex9727, I would first read everything StephenC said as it's good advice. However, your problem in this case is probably related to how many times you're iterating through your loops rather than the cost of each individual computation. Although I can't make a specific recommendation based on just your brief explanation, you should probably be using either Dynamic Programming here or using hash maps to prevent having to loop through either your inner or outer array.

Comment: Best possible answer. There are various situations in code, so it always depends. But the statement I really want to emphasize - it's simply forbidden to claim that this particular part of code makes your app slower until you make a profiling session with real data. And in most enterprise scenarios readability and maintainability of your code greatly outweights possibly (not) saved microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not, it's a good practice if you have performance issues. However when you don't, it would probably be considered as premature optimization. That optimization technique is called [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: It would also be a *premature optimization* if you have performance issues and you haven't bothered to profile to determine where the problems really are.

Comment: @StephenC, Yes, I updated the answer and quoted you since I believe it's worth mentionning it. Anyway your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is whether the function is doing something that prevents the compiler from determining that it will always return the same result. An example is if the function is reading external data such as from the disk or network.

If the compiler cannot fundamentally determine such "immutable" behavior then you should store and reuse the result of any such call.

If the compiler can indeed determine, at least in principle, that the result will be the same -- for example, a function that calculates the nth Fibonacci number -- then it depends upon the sophistication of your compiler. Functional programming languages, esp. Haskell, are specifically designed such that all functions except a few exceptions are assured to return the same value for the same arguments, and therefore all implementations do such caching automatically.

However, with languages not designed that way, of which Java is one, it is extremely unlikely that the compiler will determine that your Fibonacci code is "immutable" so to speak. Therefore, you should store and reuse the value yourself.

The final caveat is that it is not worth the additional complexity to do this for near-trivial operations such as a function that calculates a percentage.

**Update:** It seems like your question is *not* whether to store and reuse the values returned by functions, but that the functions themselves keep an internal cache. This, I would advise against except for identified hotspots that are called from disparate regions of code and for which there is no easy way for these regions of code to coordinate with each other. That is because there are a few downsides to caching such values -- you might waste some memory to cache values that may not actually be needed again; worse, such values might evict values that do end up being needed again; and third, there are extra instructions and memory accesses to check whether a value is in the cache or not.

The logic to store and reuse is best kept outside the function so that it can do more precise store and reuse than a cache.